# PostgreSQL equivalent to "SET SESSION query_cache_type = ON/OFF";

Tags: mysql, postgresql, caching

I just wanted to know what's the equivalent query in PostgreSQL to MySQL's

SET SESSION query_cache_type = ON
SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF

Comment: Why do you think you need something like this? What's your real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent. PostgreSQL has a very different internal architecture from MySQL and its caching ("shared buffers") works on another level. It does not store query results, but rather the data which is needed to compute those results (query plans and tables, basically).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/14010534715277@mail.emproshunts.com

http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg109033.html

Comment: I *believe* the only time PG caches a query plan is for a prepared statement - which causes a whole other set of issues.